# 24 hour time formatting with Swift's `Date.formatted()`

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to format a date in Swift, using the `Date.formatted()` method, to produce a time as 24-hour clock time.

```swift
import Foundation

let date = try! Date("2023-07-25T16:23:00Z", strategy: .iso8601)
print(date.formatted(.dateTime.hour(.twoDigits(amPM: .omitted)).minute()))

// Produces: 05:23
```

I'm in the UK and currently in BST, so 5:23pm is expected for an input of 16:24.  I'd like to get the output as  `17:23` *without* using `DateFormatter`.  Is there a way to configure `.hour()` to produce the 24 hour equivalent?  Or any other non-`DateFormatter` method?

Comment: Not directly related but if you want 24-hour clock the modifier `.twoDigits(amPM: .omitted)` (even `.wide`) has no effect. If you get `05:23` then the current locale is not `en_UK`. Consider that the default locale of the simulator is `en_US`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/formatstyle/timestyle) for `TimeStyle` states that *"The exact format depends on the locale"*.

So, if you *absolutely* need to use the `.formatted` (`Date.FormatStyle`) then you can pin the locale to something that defaults to 24h (don't ask me how to get them - it appears that you cannot. There is [a whole thread in the Swift forums about this](https://forums.swift.org/t/new-date-formatstyle-anyway-to-do-24-hour/52994/30)).

Keep in mind that any localized symbols in your date will be also pinned to this locale though.

From a quick experiment it seems that `en_UK` does produce a 24h time:

```
print(
    date.formatted(
        .dateTime
        .locale(.init(identifier: "en_UK"))
        .hour(.twoDigits(amPM: .omitted))
        .minute()
    )
)
```

outputs:

> 19:23

Comment: Perfect, thanks - locale was the secret sauce.

Comment: In general, this is a bad idea since people in locales that normally use 12-hour time with am/pm could be annoyed seeing the time formatted as 24-hour. I hope this is only being used in a case where the user, no matter their locale, is expecting a 24-hour format.

Comment: @HangarRash Indeed. That's why I tried to make it perfectly clear in my answer.

Comment: Agreed, both, and thanks for the emphasis.  This is one of those ongoing discussions with our designers.  If it does land on the side of "24-hour, no matter what" I am at least armed with a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Another way: using `Date.VerbatimFormatStyle`.

```
Date.now.formatted(Date.VerbatimFormatStyle(
        format: "\(hour: .twoDigits(clock: .twentyFourHour, hourCycle: .oneBased))",
        timeZone: .current,
        calendar: .current)
    )
```